# La consola siempre devuelve el caso default en vez de devolver otro resultado

Tags: c

Intento realizar un ejercicio que trata de lo siguiente:

> Se pide que escriba un programa que:
>
> 1. Muestre el listado de las habitaciones de la casa de campo.
> 2. Pida por teclado el número (dato entero) asociado a una habitación.
> 3. Muestre por pantalla la planta y el número de camas de la habitación seleccionada.
>
> Observación: Si el número introducido por el usuario, no está asociado a ninguna habitación,
> se mostrará el mensaje: "Número no asociado a habitación.".

En el lenguaje C.

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5
int hab[N] = {1,2,3,4,5};
void mostrar();
int pedirHab();
void numeroCamas(int);

int main()
{
    pedirHab();
    numeroCamas((int)pedirHab);
    return 0;
}

void mostrar() {
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        printf("%d",hab[i]);
    }
}

int pedirHab() {
    int n;
    
    printf("Ingrese un numero de habitacion: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    return n;
}

void numeroCamas(int n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 1:
        printf("La cantidad de camas es: 2");
        break;
        case 2:
        printf("La cantidad de camas es: 1");
        break;
        case 3:
        printf("La cantidad de camas es: 3");
        break;
        case 4:
        printf("La cantidad de camas es: 2");
        break;
        case 5:
        printf("La cantidad de camas es: 1");
        break;
        default: 
        printf("Numero no asociado a habitacion");
    }
}
```

La consola, SIEMPRE me devuelve el caso `default`, en vez de devolver otro resultado. ¿Alguien sabe cuál es el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pedirHab` es una función.

`(int)pedirHab` intenta convertir la función en un valor de tipo `int`. Como siempre haces lo mismo, obtienes el mismo resultado.

> *“No esperes resultados diferentes si siempre haces lo mismo."* -Albert Einstein

Cuando llamas a la función en `main`, debes guardar el valor en una variable y pasárselo a la función `numeroCamas`

```
int habitacion = pedirHab();
numeroCamas(habitacion);
```

O también puedes pasar como parámetro el resultado de la función directamente:

```
numeroCamas(pedirHab()); 
// Nota que las funciones se acompañan de paréntesis (es el operador que llama a la función).
// Sin paréntesis, para el compilador es un símbolo más. Como si de una variable se tratara.
```